# Coda Slider - Content is hidden in Safari, Chrome & IE. Works in Firefox

Tags: jquery, coda-slider

I am using Coda Slider on [my Drupal 7 website](http://premsat.co.uk/taxonomy/term/1). When a page loads on Safari, Chrome & IE, the content appears hidden, and you have to click a tab for the content to appear. This doesn't happen in Firefox.

Is there anyway to get the content to appear, without having to click on a tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked this out.

For some reason coda insets a height value of 0 to 20px on the container div.

You can fix this by adding `height:auto` to the container DIV in your style sheet.
(You might need to use an `!important` declaration to make sure the rule applies to the div).

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I found this topic in google, so i'll post here my solution. May it would be helpful for someone :)

If your content is image, just specify the `height` attribute. And content will not be hidden.

```
<img height='600'...
```